# VB.NET & SQL Server : search in multiple columns with multiple values using Like

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to get search result from VB form using multiple TextBox values to be searched in SQL Server database with `Like` operator

```
    Dim mobile As String = "%" & TextBox1.Text & "%"
    Dim name As String = "%" & TextBox2.Text & "%"
    Dim add1 As String = "%" & TextBox3.Text & "%"
    Dim add2 As String = "%" & TextBox4.Text & "%"
    Dim add3 As String = "%" & TextBox5.Text & "%"
    Dim add4 As String = "%" & TextBox6.Text & "%"
    Dim city As String = "%" & ComboBox1.Text & "%"
    Dim pin As String = "%" & TextBox7.Text & "%"
    Dim phone As String = "%" & TextBox8.Text & "%"
    Dim email As String = "%" & TextBox9.Text & "%"
    Dim gst As String = "%" & TextBox10.Text & "%"
    Dim pan As String = "%" & TextBox11.Text & "%"
    Dim mobile2 As String = "%" & TextBox12.Text & "%"
    Dim dob As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
    Dim doa As Date = DateTimePicker2.Value.Date
    Dim sms As Integer = If(CheckBox1.Checked, 1, 0)
    Dim district As String = "%" & ComboBox2.Text & "%"
    Dim state As String = "%" & ComboBox3.Text & "%"
    Dim remark As String = "%" & TextBox13.Text & "%"
    SQL.AddParam("@mobile", mobile)
    SQL.AddParam("@name", name)
    SQL.AddParam("@add1", add1)
    SQL.AddParam("@add2", add2)
    SQL.AddParam("@add3", add3)
    SQL.AddParam("@add4", add4)
    SQL.AddParam("@city", city)
    SQL.AddParam("@pin", pin)
    SQL.AddParam("@phone", phone)
    SQL.AddParam("@mobile2", mobile2)
    SQL.AddParam("@email", email)
    SQL.AddParam("@district", district)
    SQL.AddParam("@state", state)
    SQL.AddParam("@gst", gst)
    SQL.AddParam("@pan", pan)
    SQL.AddParam("@sms", sms)
    SQL.AddParam("@dob", dob)
    SQL.AddParam("@doa", doa)
    SQL.AddParam("@remark", remark)
    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM customerdata where mobile LIKE @mobile OR name LIKE @name OR add1 LIKE @add1 OR add2 LIKE @add2 OR add3 LIKE @add3 OR add4 LIKE @add4 OR city LIKE @city OR pin LIKE @pin OR phone LIKE @phone OR mobile2 LIKE @mobile2 OR email LIKE @email OR dist LIKE @district OR state LIKE @state OR gst LIKE @gst OR pan LIKE @pan OR dob=@dob OR doa=@doa OR remark LIKE @remark OR smsok=@sms; ")
    If SQL.HasException(True) Then Exit Sub
    DataGridView1.DataSource = SQL.DBDT
```

I am using class to create `SqlConnection` object, so SQL.AddParam and SQL.ExecQuery are part of that.

Issue is as user fills just couple of textbox and rest are "" the result thrown by above command fetches all the records.

What's the best way to capture just the fields which are having input and ignore rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I build my parameters collection and a Select query for a dynamic search where the user can choose one or some or all the criteria.

```
Public Shared Function DynamicSearchCoffees(itgRoaster As Integer, strRoast As String, strType As String, strRating As String, bolBold As Boolean, bolFavorite As Boolean) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim bolNeedAnd As Boolean = False
    Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
    sb.Append("SELECT Coffees.ID, Coffees.[Name], Coffees.RoasterID, Roasters.[Name] As 'RoasterName', Coffees.[Type],Coffees.Rating, Coffees.Comment, Coffees.Description, Coffees.Roast, Coffees.IsExtraBold, Coffees.IsFavorite
                From Coffees Inner Join Roasters on Coffees.RoasterID = Roasters.ID Where ")

    Using cn As New SqlConnection(conStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand()
        If itgRoaster <> 0 Then
            sb.Append("RoasterID = @RoasterID ")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RoasterID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = itgRoaster
            bolNeedAnd = True
        End If
        If strRoast <> "" Then
            If bolNeedAnd Then
                sb.Append($"AND ")
            End If
            sb.Append($"Roast = @Roast ")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Roast", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = strRoast
            bolNeedAdd = True
        End If
        If strType <> "" Then
            If bolNeedAnd Then
                sb.Append($"AND ")
            End If
            sb.Append($"Type = @Type ")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = strType
            bolNeedAnd = True
        End If
        If strRating <> "" Then
            If bolNeedAnd Then
                sb.Append($"AND ")
            End If
            sb.Append($"Rating = @Rating ")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rating", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = strRating
            bolNeedAnd = True
        End If
        If bolBold Then
            If bolNeedAnd Then
                sb.Append($"AND ")
            End If
            sb.Append("IsExtraBold = 1 ")
            bolNeedAnd = True
        End If
        If bolFavorite Then
            If bolNeedAnd Then
                sb.Append($"AND ")
            End If
            sb.Append("IsFavorite = 1 ")
        End If
        sb.Append("Order By Coffees.[Name], RoasterName;")
        cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to group all textboxes in a container (panel, for instance) and iterate through them. For each textbox, you check whether it is completed or not. If it is, you add the param and the corresponding part in the query. If you can't group them, you'll have to perform if statements on each textbox with the same condition. I'd suggest using a StringBuilder for this and use its result as the SQL.ExecQuery method argument. If you need further explanations, comment my answer and I'll edit it. Hope this helps, have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply, will try to work on your suggestion and ping you back